# How to display the custom markers/annotations in order on map using swift

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mkannotation

I used mapbox and swift to add custom markers on the map. Now I want to display these markers one by one on the map, NOT simultaneously.

How can I display these markers one by one on the map in the example below?

Visit https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/annotation-views/

Answer (score 1):

The example that you linked to uses the `-addAnnotations:` method, which can be used to add an array of `MGLAnnotation` objects to a map view. In order to add individual annotations, use the [-addAnnotation:](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.3.0/Classes/MGLMapView.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapView(im)addAnnotation:) method.